# ServiceStack: Access Session info from Javascript

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm creating a SPA using ServiceStack and AngularJs. When a user logs in I set some variables in the OnAuthenticated method:

```
    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        var sessionUser = session.TranslateTo<AppUserSession>();
        var user = _userRepo.LoadUser(session.UserAuthName);

        var userSettings = ConfigurationSettings.Load(user);

        var customers = _customerRepo.ToList();
        sessionUser.UserName = user.UserName;
        sessionUser.DisplayName = user.DisplayName;
        sessionUser.CustomerCount = customers.Count;
        sessionUser.CustomerRecordId = customers.First().RecordID;
        sessionUser.RefreshRate = userSettings.RefreshRate;

        authService.SaveSession(sessionUser, SessionExpiry);
    }
```

So my question is, how can I then access this information in Javascript? Do I need to create a Service which exposes them or is it returned in a HTTP header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to create a Service which exposes them or is it returned in a HTTP header?

The custom parameters you add to the session are not exposed in any way by ServiceStack, by default.

## Expose from Login Result:

You can return this information in the response from your login, as part of a successful response.

At the moment the default response from ServiceStack's `CredentialsAuthProvider` is:

```cs
return new AuthResponse {
    UserName = userName,
    SessionId = session.Id,
    ReferrerUrl = referrerUrl
};
```

You can customise this in your custom authentication provider, by overriding the `Authenticate` method.

Most of the code in this method is copied from the [original `CredentialsAuthProvider` authenticate method (here)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs) and then adapted to use your custom session type (`AppUserSession`) and populate a custom response.

```cs
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request)
{
    var userName = request.UserName;
    var password = request.Password;

    if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, userName))
    {
        authService.RemoveSession();
        session = authService.GetSession();
    }

    if (TryAuthenticate(authService, userName, password))
    {
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;

        if (session.UserAuthName == null)
        {
            session.UserAuthName = userName;
        }

        OnAuthenticated(authService, session, null, null);

        var sessionUser = authService.GetSession() as AppUserSession;

        // Return your Authentication Response DTO here
        return new {
            UserName = userName,
            SessionId = session.Id,
            DisplayName = sessionUser.DisplayName,
            CustomerCount = sessionUser.CustomerCount,
            ...
        };
    }

    throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Invalid UserName or Password");
}
```

## Expose using a Service:

You could expose them by writing a custom service that would return this additional information, but that then requires another request after successfully logging in, and that would add more delay for the user, and data overhead.

```cs
[Route("/SessionInfo", "GET")]
public class GetSessionInfoRequest : IReturn<SessionInfo>

public class SessionInfo
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCount { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Authenticate]
public class SessionInfoService : Service
{
    public SessionInfo Get(GetSessionInfoRequest request)
    {
        var sessionUser = SessionAs<AppUserSession>();
        return new SessionInfo {
            UserName = sessionUser.UserName,
            DisplayName = sessionUser.DisplayName,
            CustomerCount = sessionUser.CustomerCount,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

The only real benefit of exposing as a service, is you would be able to call it later, and get fresher values of the data (if it has changed) without having to re-authenticate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Scott when I access the `sessionUser` object in my `Authenticate` method it is an empty object with no values set?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Have you moved `var sessionUser = session as AppUserSession;` to after the `OnAuthenticated` call? I changed the code a couple of minutes ago?

Comment: Yeah I moved it but it was still empty, want me to start a new question?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Nope just change that to `var sessionUser = authService.GetSession() as AppUserSession;` That should do it.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Cool glad it is working. I have updated the answer with that fix.