# ServiceStack CredentialsAuthProvidercheck if authenticated

Tags: servicestack

Is there an easy way I can easily check whether I am currently logged into ServiceStack Auth by using a REST endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack v4 has been recently updated, *Friday 16 May*, ([in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/242de40773022aca0d90e85303691d010e06a36d)) to support returning session information by making a `GET` request to the `Authenticate` route `/auth`.

[image: Session]

Thus if you have a valid session you will get a response such as:

```js
{
    "UserId":"1",
    "SessionId":"1",
    "UserName":"bob",
    "ResponseStatus":{}
}
```

Otherwise you can always create a service that returns information about your session yourself. [See my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23652474/1295344) for an example of this method.

Hope that helps.